# Best way to store 2 dimensional array data

Tags: database, postgresql

I have 2 dimensional data:

```
   user x time_series   of events.
```

What would be the best way to store the data if I have to do operations (SQL and computing metrics on time_series) ?

```
Schema 1 :
  user_id by rows,  column containining string dates  t0,t1,...


Schema 2: (all in the rows)
   transaction_id, user_id, ti, ...
```

Most of the computations are done by user_id ....

Comment: Take a look onto this: https://grisha.org/blog/2015/09/23/storing-time-series-in-postgresql-efficiently/

Comment: It seems a super-hard, very data dependant issues...